# Which is this code written in?

Tags: html, web

```
{% if booking.car_type %}<b>Car Type</b>: {{
```

I just want to know in which language is the code between the {% %} is written in

Thank you

Comment: These are django templates block

Answer (score 0):

Django templates ... for sure you must check in Google for much deeper knowledge.